# save multiple images from array php using multi curl

Tags: php, arrays, multithreading, image, curl

I know via single curl request we can save image, But if we have php array containing URLs with hundreds of urls is it possible to use multicurl requests to save images simultaneously. as multi curl will reduce the time dramatically.

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/image.php');
$fp = fopen('/my/folder/flower.gif', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

this is code for single curl request. How can i modify it for multi curl for array something like

```
$url={'http://http://example.com/image1.gif',
'http://http://example.com/image2.gif',
'http://http://example.com/image3.gif',
'http://http://example.com/image4.gif',
'http://http://example.com/image5.gif',
'http://http://example.com/image6.gif',
'http://http://example.com/image7.gif'};
```

Comment: looks like examples in the docs for [curl_multi_init](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) show how to do this.

Comment: I can't find that example... can u pls write bellow in answer ?